# Sound is barely audible

Tags: windows-7, audio

After working great for a long time, the sound on my system is now barely audible. It's not the speakers as it is also really low with headphones. Volume is maxed out on the speaker, in the application and in windows, but I can still barely hear it.

I'm using the on board sound from an intel dg965wh mobo. I tried getting a driver from them, but it didn't seem to do anything. I don't think they support windows 7 on this mobo.

Any idea on how to isolate or resolve  this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I am surprised you got any audio out - Intel does not officially support this motherboard at all with Windows 7 and there is no official sound driver.

I personally had this problem the other day (on another 985 motherboard) and got no where.

In the end, the easiest solution was to use a cheap £5 sound card that was compatible with Windows 7. It worked fine and I would suggest you try the same.